# What encoding does the 'text' response type option in HttpClient use?

Tags: angular, typescript, encoding, angular-httpclient

When making an HTTP request like this:

```
return HttpClient.get("url", { headers: requestHeaders, responseType: 'text'});
```

What encoding is used when turning the response into a string?

Comment: That really depends on the server that sends the response. In short, there's no way to know without sending the request.

Comment: That's [delegated](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5bd188a394d30053099e2c83fe79136d590e5399/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L165-L168) to the underlying [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), Angular/`HttpClient` doesn't decide that. It depends on the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type), the default's generally UTF-8: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#response-body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the official Angular Repository, for the Http Client we can look under [common/http](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/main/packages/common/http/src):

While looking into the official repo, you can only find a mention of encodings in one particular case, as seen [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/http/src/request.ts#L420):

```
if (this.body instanceof HttpParams) {
  return 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
}
```

Checking in the network tab of an Angular application, you can see that it does not specify the encoding type, when sending a request, however, the response headers of the response may include it in the `content-type` property
if the sending server specified it.

Like mentioned in the comments, default is utf-8, as mentioned by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).